# Index of a function and a gradient flow

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

We know `index` of function $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ at critical point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the number of negative eigen values of Hessian matrix $DF^2(x_0)$. By intuition, it's also the number of decreasing direction. Let's call $F$'s index $F$-index. When $F$ is viewed as height function, then `sink`'s $F$-index is a $0$, and `source`($2$),`saddle`($1$).

For dynamical system $X'=DF(X)$, negative eigen value of $DF^2(x_0)$ implies moving back to critical point $x_0$. In this case, `sink`'s $F$-index is $2$, `source`($0$), `saddle`($1$).

The concept of `source/sink/saddle` is different according to the same index. Is it the reason that  gradient flow is defined as $X'=-DF(X)$ by convention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of gradient flow going against the gradient comes from natural sciences, not from the desire to match two mathematical definitions. In physics, a system tends to minimize  its potential energy, and therefore evolves in the direction    opposite the gradient. The force with potential $U$ is $-\nabla U$. The direction of net flow of some substance in a mixture is opposite to the gradient of its concentration.

This point of view influences the definitions of index of Morse-Smale dynamical systems. As seen [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Morse-Smale_system) or [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Morse-Smale_systems), they are commonly  expressed  in the form $\dot X=-\nabla F(X)$. The index of a stationary point of $F$ was already defined as the number of negative Hessian eigenvalues. From the dynamical system point of view, the index is taken  as the dimension of the *unstable* manifold, so that it coincides with the previous notion of index.

My point is, it's the $-\nabla$  that influences the definitions of index, not the other way around.

When someone decides to fight the influence of physics  and define gradient flows as $\dot X=\nabla F(X)$, they end up with  slightly inconsistent definitions; no big deal.

Comment: Both indices are index of $F$ at critical point $x_0$, i.e. number of negative eigen values of $D^2F(x_0)$. I don't mention the degree/index of a vector field stationary point.

Comment: @MartinWang In the question you have two versions of index: the first one gives 0 for a sink, the other gives 2. What is the definitions of the second one?

Comment: It's still the number of negative eigen values of $D^2F(x_0)$. A sink in the sense of vector field is corresponding to the index $2$, which is not literally consistent with the sink concept by intuition.

Comment: Actually, it's called Morse Index. In my understanding, when considering a function $F(X)$, the morse index at critical point is number of negative eigen values of hessian matrix. however, when considering a gradient flow $X'=F(X)$, the morse index is defined as number of positive eigen values.

Comment: @MartinWang Okay, I clarified the answer.